# Why am I seeing the same 3 Spider Solitaire games today that I saw 2 days ago

Tags: solitaire

For the third time in 5 or 6 games today and yesterday I am seeing the same Spider Solitaire layout that I saw two days go. These three games all had very unique patterns, and took a large number of moves to solve, nearly 5,000 the second time on one because I had one move wrong early on that took a while to identify. Does anyone know how this happens? I'm running 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

The random number generator could have been seeded with the same seed, which would cause the same sequence of random number to be generated. The RNG in Microsoft's C library repeats every ~32,000 numbers (which is pretty abysmal), so there's effectively only that many seeds.

Different seeds:

```
>perl -E"say srand; say join ' ', map int(rand(52))+1, 1..10;"
1819759215  # The seed
41 35 23 9 35 2 41 11 50 51

>perl -E"say srand; say join ' ', map int(rand(52))+1, 1..10;"
994223390
47 13 12 51 35 7 37 42 11 2
```

But what if the same seed was picked the next day:

```
>perl -E"srand(994223390); say join ' ', map int(rand(52))+1, 1..10;"
47 13 12 51 35 7 37 42 11 2
```